# Python error when writing a class?

Tags: python, class, syntax-error

I am working on the following problem:

Write a shopping cart class to implement a shopping cart that you often find on websites where you could purchase some goods. Think about what things you could store in a cart and also what operations you could perform on the cart. To simplify matters, you could consider the website to be an electronics e-store that has goods like flat-panel TVs, radios, iPods, camcorders, and so on.

This is my code so far:

```
class ShoppingCart(object):
    def __init__(self, name = "", address = ""):
        self.items = []
        self.total = 0
        self.shopper = name
        self.address = address

    def get_address(self):
        return self.address
    def get_address(self,address):
        self.address = address

    def add_item(self, T):
        "Add tuple(name, quantity, price, ID)"
    self.items.append(T)
    self.total = sum(t[2] for t in self.items)

    def delete_item(self, T):
        "Delete tuple(name, quantity, price, ID)"
        if T in self.items:
            self.items.remove(T)
            self.total = sum([t[2]] for t in self.items)

    def print_cart(self):
        print("\n cart:")
        print("\t", "Item", \t\, "price", "quantity")

    for T in self.items:
        print("\t", T[0],"\t", T[2], "\t", T[1])
        print("\n Total:", self.total)


    def test_cart():
        "Demonstrate use of class"
        s = ShoppingCart('Rich')
        s.add_item(("iPod Nano", 1, 150.00, '12345'))
        s.add_item(("The Holiday (DVD)", 2, 18.00, '14443'))
        s.set_address('123 Timber, St. Louis, MO, 63130')
        s.print_cart()

test_cart()
```

I get an error saying:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-b4071917f558>", line 27
    print("\t", "Item", \t\, "price", "quantity")
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Does anyone know why this error is occurring? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You missed the double quotes for the \t\

Comment: Get a new error: 
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-254519afb7dc> in <module>()
      1 #10
----> 2 class ShoppingCart(object):
      3     def __init__(self, name = "", address = ""):
      4         self.items = []
      5         self.total = 0

<ipython-input-14-254519afb7dc> in ShoppingCart()
     14     def add_item(self, t):
     15         "Add tuple(name, quantity, price, ID)"
---> 16     self.items.append(t)
     17     self.total = sum(t[2] for t in self.items)
     18 

NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: You have wrong indentation for the code in `add_item(self, T)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add colon:

```
print("\t", "Item", "\t", "price", "quantity")
```

And you could use a simple way:

```
print("\t Item \t price quantity")
```

Comment: You added quotes, not colons.

Comment: Thank you so much! I seem to now be getting another error:

Comment: Now getting a new error that says "self" is not defined in lines 2 or 16...any idea why?

Comment: You have bad indentations in your `add_item` method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the error message given. You cannot print out `\t\`. I think you meant `"\t"`.